# logging last eight character of the thread id?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my multithreaded program, I am logging process id and thread id.  Thread id is generated using pthread_self() function. when I print in hex, generally it has 12 characters out of which first four are always common and I don't want to log them.

What is the best way in C++ to print last 8 characters, I tried to use boost::format but couldn't figure out how to print last 8 characters.

e.g
Here printing process id in decimal and thread id in hex.

```
 std::cout << boost::format("%5d|%8X") %getpid() %pthread_self()
```

I have made it work with below solution but I don't like the magic number 10000000000

```
std::cout << boost::format("%5d|%8X") %getpid() %(pthread_self()%10000000000)
```

NOTE: For simplicity, here I used std::cout. In my application, I use boost::log so if there is a way to do using boost log, that's preferred.

Here is an example: 7f08 is common and doesn't add any value in debugging.

14833|7f084b7fe700

14833|7f084bfff700

14833|7f0850dec700

14833|7f08515ed700

14833|7f0851dee700

14833|7f08525ef700

14833|7f0852df0700

14833|7f08535f1700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your magic constant should be in hex:

```
pthread_self() & 0xffffffff
```

This lets bits in the bottom 8 hex digits pass through unchanged, but sets bits in the higher hex digits to 0.  They should then be suppressed, since you haven't specified leading 0 printing.

Comment: this is better solution than mine but I am still looking if there is a way to set/format the width and print only last 8 characters.

Comment: Not without additionally performing the above step or doing string manipulation.  Formatters were not designed for this.

Answer (score 2):

1) declare a char[13] variable on stack
2) sprintf there your thread id in %x form
3) then if you take a pointer to 4-th element of the array it will be your 8-char string - you can log it via whatever you like

Comment: This will fail if the leading characters are zero, since the result will be shifted left.

Comment: Agreed. +1 to your answer for elegance :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the computation in a new function properly named, like `last_part_of_thread_id()`. Then the code will not look that magic inside such a function.